# assert current_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, capybara

```
 require 'test_helper'

     class MyTest < ActionController::IntegrationTest

      test "view posts from login page" do
      visit("/logins/new")
      find_field('Username').set('abode')
      find_field('Password').set('efghi')
      click_link_or_button('Login')
      #assert current_path == "/logins/new"
      assert current_path == "/posts/index" 
      end

    end
```

In the code above, first assert is passing whereas the second is failing. It should happen otherwise. After `click_link_or_button('Login')` is executed the page logins I am assuming. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For anyone searching this issue nowadays -- with Capybara 2.5 you can do

```
assert_current_path('/posts/index')
```

and it will use Capybara's waiting behavior to check if the path changes to what is expected

Answer (score 1):

What are you actually trying to test? It is not possible for current_path to be both "/logins/new" and "/posts/index" at the same time.

I would say move the first assert to just after the visit step. Then your test will make sense. If it is still failing, then the login action isn't working.

Comment: Oh no actually I was commenting one and running another. This is in integration test.

Comment: I put the first assert after visit, it's passing.

Comment: @Vinisa The whole test is passing, or just the first assert?

Comment: `assert current_path == "/logins/new"` is working which means its not logging in and the `assert current_path == "/posts/index"` is not which ideally should.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `current_path` variable hasn't yet updated its new path value. So you need to wait for the path. I did it with two things: [fixed a bug preveting correct `current_path` variable update](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1460), and [`rspec-wait` gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/rspec-wait). So the expectation code is the following:

```
wait_for{ page }.to have_current_path(posts_path)
```